# jquery - highlight next row rather than the one that was clicked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to highlight a table row when a user clicks it. But instead of highlighting the one that is clicked, I would like to highlight the row below the row which is clicked.

I have a code for highlighting the clicked row, but I don't know how to highlight the next row.  And the page is going to be dynamically generated with the server side language, so I would like the code to be a little flexible.

```
        <table class="table" id="traits">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-7">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th class="col-md-1 survey_header">Just like me</th>
                  <th class="col-md-1 survey_header">Very much like me</th>
                  <th class="col-md-1 survey_header">Somewhat like me</th>
                  <th class="col-md-1 survey_header">Not much like me</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2 survey_header">Not at all like me</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="">
                  <td class="survey_trait"><strong>trait 1</strong></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait1" value="5"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait1" value="4"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait1" value="3"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait1" value="2"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait1" value="1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="">
                  <td class="survey_trait"><strong>trait 2</strong></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait2" value="5"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait2" value="4"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait2" value="3"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait2" value="2"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait2" value="1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="">
                  <td class="survey_trait"><strong>trait 3</strong></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait3" value="5"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait3" value="4"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait3" value="3"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait3" value="2"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait3" value="1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="">
                  <td class="survey_trait"><strong>trait 4</strong></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait4" value="5"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait4" value="4"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait4" value="3"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait4" value="2"></td>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="trait4" value="1"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table>



      <script>
        // When the document is ready
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#traits tr").click(function() {
           var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            //remove any selected siblings 
            $tr.siblings().removeClass('selected');
            //toggle current row
            $tr.toggleClass('selected');
          })



        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add .next() and change the selector for removing the class to:

```
$("#traits tr").click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this);
    //remove any selected siblings 
    $('#traits tr').removeClass('selected');
    //toggle current row
    $tr.next().toggleClass('selected');
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/58st8j3n/3)**

Answer (score 0):

In the script use the following code:

```
<script>
    // When the document is ready
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#traits tr").click(function() {
           //remove all selected classes if any before adding it to the next one
           $("tr").removeClass('selected');
           $(this).next().addClass('selected')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. is there an API for telling me if the row is the last row or not?

Comment: You can use the if statement and array length to program that.